# LINQ Table does not contain a definition for count (or any other Queryable extension methods)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We are changing some legacy code to use LINQ to SQL.

In a seperate test throwaway class I tried making my db context and I can do

```
mydbcontext.mytable.Count()
```

fine, and it's all intellisensed.

However, when trying to implement this in the class (which is in the same assembly), the Queryable methods, such as Count, Where, etc are no longer valid.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. We were tripped up on it because I would type Count() and expect VS to give me the option to import System.Linq. It seems like VS doesn't recognise extension methods for auto-import thing

Comment: Calm down, it wouldn't let me accept it as it had only been posted x minutes go :)

Comment: I often ask more difficult ones than these ;)